# Norm of linear functional on product space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $\Phi:L^{p}\times L^p\to\mathbb{R}$ be the linear functional given by
$$\Phi(h_0,h_1) = \int_If_0h_0+\int_If_1h_1$$
where $f_0,f_1\in L^{q}$, $1/p+1/q=1$. Consider the norm on $L^p\times L^p$ given by
$$||(h_0,h_1)|| = ||h_0||_p+||h_1||_p$$
I must prove that  $$||\Phi|| = \max\{||f_0||_q,||f_1||_q\}$$
I have shown the inequality $\leq$, I just can't prove the reverse one. I've tried finding an $h$ such that $\Phi$ attains the maximum, but have failed. Any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The norm of dual operator over $L^p(\Bbb R^N)\times L^p(\Bbb R^N)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047496/the-norm-of-dual-operator-over-lp-bbb-rn-times-lp-bbb-rn)

Comment: @Invisible Not quite, I don't understand why $||\Phi||\geq \max\{||f||_1,||f_2||\}$ if we set $x_i = 0$, or, in this case, $h_i=0$, since we would only have the inequality $||\Phi||\geq |\Phi(0,h_1)|=|\int_I f_1h_1|$ for $||h_1||=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the functions
$$
h_j(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\|f_j\|_q^{1-q} \cdot \frac{|f_j(x)|^{q}}{f_j(x)} & f_j(x) \neq 0\\
0 & \text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}
\qquad j=0,1.
$$
Notably, $\|h_j\|_p = 1$ for each $j$. It must be true that $|\Phi(h)|$ attains its maximum (over unit $h$) either $(h_0,0)$ or $(0,h_1)$.

Comment: This would seem to work, except  $||h_j||_p = ||f_j||_q$, not 1, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @MathNewbie It's very possible that I normalized incorrectly; I'll check more thoroughly if I get the chance. If you're confident, feel free to edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing it to $||f_j||^{-q}\cdot\frac{|f_j(x)|^q}{f_j(x)}$ and then I get norm 1, but then $\Phi(h_0,0) =\Phi(0,h_1)= 1$ as well, so I'm not sure how to procced.